# Create subscription for Sharepoint List returns 403 forbidden

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to fetch items from Sharepoint list. Everything has worked well and I have a token, which works for getting items from the list

Now I want to get a notice, when any item gets updated on that list. For that, I tried to create webhook with subscription with the same token. However when trying to create subscription, the API returns 403.

```
var subscription = new Subscription
            {
                Resource = "sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/",
                NotificationUrl = "{notification url}",
                ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(2),
                ChangeType = "updated"
            };
var res = await graphServiceClient.Subscriptions
          .Request()
          .AddAsync(subscription);
```

I have set the required Sites.ReadWrite.All permission to my app registration. The call to the API returns me

```
{
Error: Code: ExtensionError
Message: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.]
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    request-id: 99445d24-8d09-45a5-98e7-05b99587fd7f
    date: 2020-04-26T21:53:21
ClientRequestId: 99445d24-8d09-45a5-98e7-05b99587fd7f
}
```

Am I targeting wrong resource or is there any other permission, that app needs?

Edit: also tried using certificate to authorize, still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

For creating a [new webhook subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/lists/create-subscription), the application must have at least edit permissions to the SharePoint list where the subscription will be created (if the App is Azure AD). If the application is a SharePoint Add-in, You must grant 'Manage' or higher permission.

Comment: Hi @Nishant. I am also facing this exact same issue. I am using an azure ad app, and was wondering if you could clarify where we add the edit permission to the sharepoint list?

The link you sent says the Application "Office 365 SharePoint Online" needs permission "Read and write items and lists in all site collections." Is this something that is configured on sharepoint online or in azure? and where about exactly?

Comment: @Nishant I'm using Graph API, not sending request directly to SharePoint. [As docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) reference here, I've set Sites.ReadWrite.All to my application. There is also an issue created on Graph API [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/7786#issue-601453574) which states the same problem as I have. The question is, has Graph API some problems or is it somewhere in my configuration. Also tried using certificate based auth for application as suggested on Github.

Comment: @simondefreeze The API permission can be added from Azure AD. Please follow the document - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-configure-prerequisites-for-reporting-api#grant-permissions)

Comment: @dannnnnnnnnnnn - Let me investigate and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks @Nishant, however I had already set the 'Site.ReadWrite.All' permission in AD. I misinterpreted the link thinking there was another place I needed to set permissions.

Comment: @simondefreeze I tried this in my lab and it worked fine for me. I would suggest you look at the token and check if it has 'Site.ReadWrite.All' in roles claim. You can check that using jwt.io